# JavaFX: ScheduledService does not trigger SUCCEEDED state change after each iteration

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

I am experiencing a strange bug that a `ScheduledService` does not trigger `ChangeListener` when it successfully completes any iteration.

This is how this can be replicated:

```
final ScheduledService<Void> service = new ScheduledService<Void>()
{
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Task<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};

service.setOnSucceeded(event ->
{
    System.out.println("onSucceeded() triggered!");
});

service.stateProperty().addListener((obs, o, n) ->
{
    System.out.println(n);
});

service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(2));

service.start();
```

Output:

```
READY
SCHEDULED
SCHEDULED
RUNNING
onSucceeded() triggered!
READY
SCHEDULED
SCHEDULED
RUNNING
onSucceeded() triggered!
READY
SCHEDULED
SCHEDULED
```

This is strange because `onSucceeded()` event is triggered, but the `ChangeListener` does not get a corresponding value change. Of course, I can definitely use `setOnSucceeded()` to do all my stuff, but it is still weird because I have handled all states in the `ChangeListener` except `SUCCEEDED`.

Does this count as a bug in the API?

Comment: Yeah that looks like a bug. I can't quite figure out exactly where it is: `Service` binds its state to the `Task`'s state when it starts a task, and there's some fairly convoluted code that unbinds it when it finishes. It looks like `ScheduledService` is somehow unbinding that state too early. It's also weird that you see two transitions to `SCHEDULED`.

Comment: @James_D Seems like I found someone who agrees with me that something is weird with the API. Submitted a bug report for this, but it's probably going to be fixed in JDK 10 or 11, considering there's a workaround for this.